# If $G$ is a group, $H,K \leq G$, $K \subseteq H$, $\left[G:H\right]$ and $\left[H:K\right]$ both finite then...

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $G$ is a group, $H$ and $K$ both subgroups of $G$, $K \subseteq H$, $\left[G:H\right]$ and $\left[H:K\right]$ both finite then $\left[G:K\right]=\left[G:H\right]\cdot\left[ H:K \right].$

I am not sure if this is standard notation but $\left[ G : K \right]$ denotes the number of right or left cosets of $K$ in $G$.

I haven't tried to do the case where if $G$ is finite but I imagine the result would immediately follow by using Lagrange's Theorem. I am trying to think about the case where $G$ is infinite.

I at least made an example to show myself that the index $\left[ G: K \right]$ could be a finite number but $K$ could have size of infinity. Any leads?

Thanks very much

Comment: $[G:K]=[G:H][H:K]$ holds without any finiteness assumptions (as an equality of cardinal numbers). More precisely, there is a bijection $G/H \times H/K \to G/K$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write $G=\bigcup_{i=i}^hg_iH$ as a union of left cosets for $H$, and similarly $H=\bigcup_{j=i}^kh_jK$, then you can also write $G=\bigcup_{i=i}^h\bigcup_{j=i}^kg_ih_jK$ as a union of left cosets for $K$. It is a simple verification that all these cosets are disjoint: if the indices $i$ differ you are in different left cosets of $H$, while in case the indices $i$ are the same, left multiplication by $g_i^{-1}$ will map you to distinct left cosets for $K$ inside $H$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Each coset of $H$ in $G$ is partitioned into $[H:K]$ cosets of $K$ in $G$.